# Display Taxonomy Term for CPT on single-CPT.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single

I've been having issues with this all morning and need some help.

So I made a custom post type called Equipment, then made a custom taxonomy called Equipment Types.  On single-equipment.php I can get it to display the title, content and custom fields associated with the post, but I can't get the Equipment Type selected to display.

I've looked through the get_terms codex, and I can get it to list all the terms for Equipment Type that have posts associated with them, but not the one that was selected for the specific post.

So if I have made a new Equipment post titled "Molo H8500" and the Equipment Type Tax Term is "Speaker", I'm looking to have the single-equipment.php just display Speaker. So for example the page would display:

Title : `Molo H8500`

Content : `The MOLO H8500 speaker is a...`

Custom fields : `Height: 48"` and `Widght: 36"`

Custom Taxonomy : `Equipment Type: Speaker (can't get to display)`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want is [`get_the_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'equipment_type' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: gah this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much Milo!